# coldfusion StructFindValue not working

Tags: coldfusion, struct

I have many structures, I'm using StructFindValue() to determine if a a key occurs many times.

I get the expected array returned for "singles", however I get an empty array for "doubles" and "triples" - this code is actually inside a different code segment, -my is a structure in itself...

If I try ANY of the lines  "x= StructFindValue( y, 3, 'all' );" in a stand alone template - CF finds the '2' and '3' values just fine - I get an array with the data - but inthe above code - ONLY the values of '1' return anything...

I'm confused.

---

**UPDATE**

OK, in response to the request for more information, my server details are:

```
    Version             ColdFusion 10,282462
    Edition             Developer  
    Operating System    Windows XP  
    Java Version        1.6.0_29   
    OS Version          5.1  
    Update Level        /C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/updates/chf10000002.jar  
    Adobe Driver Version   4.1 (Build 0001)
```

As you can see from the code example below, my array has a few different names, of differing repetitive nature. I want to know which values repeat a specified number of times. As stated above, the `structkeyFind()` works IF (and only) on the key value of `1`. It doesn't work with the key values of `2`, `3` (or 4 or 5 etc, not included here for brevity).

```
<cfscript>
   _myArry = listToArray('bob,bob,bob,joe,jane,jane,john,john,john,alex,greg');
   _myStats = getDataStats( _myArry );
   writeDump( _myStats );
</cfscript>

<cffunction name="getDataStats">
   <cfargument name="data" required="yes" type="array" >

    <cfscript>
    var _hv = {};

    // default some values
    _hv.vals = {};
    _hv.threes = false;
    _hv.twos = false;
    _hv.ones =false;

    // loop the data put it into separate containers
    for ( var i=1; i LTE arrayLen( arguments.data ); i++ ) {            
        switch ( lcase( arguments.data[i] ) ) {
            case 'bob': // bob 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'bob' ) ) { _hv.vals.bob = _hv.vals.bob + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.bob = 1; }
            break;      
            case 'joe': // joe 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'joe' ) ) { _hv.vals.joe = _hv.vals.joe + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.joe = 1; }
            break;
            case 'jane': // jane 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'jane' ) ) { _hv.vals.jane = _hv.vals.jane + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.jane = 1; }
            break;
            case 'john': // john 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'john' ) ) { _hv.vals.john = _hv.vals.john + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.john = 1; }
            break;  
            case 'alex': // alex 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'alex' ) ) { _hv.vals.alex = _hv.vals.alex + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.alex = 1; }
            break;  
            case 'greg': // greg 
                if ( structKeyExists( _hv.vals, 'greg' ) ) { _hv.vals.greg = _hv.vals.greg + 1; }
                else { _hv.vals.greg = 1; }
            break;      
        }
    }

    // give me a return struct for testing so i can 'see' where I'm at
    var _thisReturn = {
        'threes' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, 3, 'all' ),
        'twos' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, 2, 'all' ),
        'ones' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, 1, 'all' ),
        'values' = arguments.data
    };
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn _thisReturn />
</cffunction>
```

---

In an attempt to 'cast' the values, I have tried each of these variations. However the results are UNCHANGED from the original.

```
'ones' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, '1', 'all' ),
'twos' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, '2', 'all' ),
'threes' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, '3', 'all' ),
```

And then

```
'ones' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, val( 1 ), 'all' ),
'twos' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, val( 2 ), 'all' ),
'threes' = StructFindValue( _hv.vals, val( 3 ), 'all' ),
```

Comment: If that *exact* code works by itself, then something in the surrounding code is different. That is the part we need to see. Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that produces the "bad" results ie empty array.

Comment: What engine and version of CF? I just ran this on CF9 and i got expected values for all 3 tests. Edit: As Leigh said, we can't help you from the above code example.

Comment: running CF10 locally...
would like to give the surrounding code- but it's extensive - give me some time to whittle it down to it's essence... the thing that is confusing is that the value of "1" gives me a return, the value of "2" does not - even though I can dump the struct directly BEFORE the structFindValue() and it clearly HAS values of "2".

So i totally agree it may be something in the code surrounding - but then why does the value of "1" work???

Give me a while to isolate and reduce the code.

Comment: I've run this on CF10, CF9, Railo 4.0.0.13 and OpenBD 2.0.2.  And it runs fine on all of them.  So whatever your problem is, it is not that code. Also pls provide the exact CF version you're running.  Can you please confirm that if you run that *exact* code (other than fixing the missing semi-colon which prevents it from even compiling), you do not get expected results?

Comment: Remember structs are passed by reference perhaps you are modifying the struct else where or have not correctly `var`'d it within a function definition.

Comment: see above additions for answers to questions. thx

Comment: That code block works fine for me. (Dumps out expected results). What does _"it doesn't work on the key values of 2 or 3"_ mean - are you getting an error or missing results?

Comment: Also, you can change that long switch/case block to just two lines...

`if ( NOT StructKeyExists( _hv.vals , arguments.data[i] ) ) { _hv.vals[lcase(arguments.data[i])] = 0; }`

`_hv.vals[arguments.data[i]]++;`

Comment: Oh wait... just tested your code on CF10 and it fails - returns empty arrays for threes and twos. Seems like a strange bug in CF10 then. :/

Comment: My guess is this may be something to do with how CF is storing the values - since it's converting between numbers and strings, it's possibly storing different representations for non-1 numbers. Or something like that... doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Peter - "doesn't work" - means specifically:
I expect a structure with 4 keys "ones,twos,threes,values"
1) "values" should contain an array that was passed in, it does.
2) "ones" should contain an array of structures showing values that occur only once in the array; Joe, Greg, Alex. it does
3) "twos" should contain an array of structures showing values that occur twice in the array; jane. it does NOT, it's gives me an empty array.
4) "threes" should contain an array of structures showing values that occur three times in the array; bob,john - it does NOT - it's gives me an empty array.

Comment: @Peter - you may be right about the value vs. the string. but I don't know how to remedy that or test that.

Comment: see above for code attempts...

Comment: See my answer below - the missing ones are probably `2.0` or similar representation. You could possibly do two StructFindValue calls and merge the results, but that seems rather icky. If this is a simple one dimension struct I'd just loop through it and compare actual values with an if/EQ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here appears to be how CF is storing / displaying / comparing the values.

Here is a simple demonstration of the problem:

```
<cfset Data = 
    { Bob  : 2
    , Joe  : 1+1
    , Jane : "2"
    , John : 2.0
    , Alex : 4/2
    } />

<cfdump var=#Data# />

<cfdump var=#StructFindValue(Data,2,"all")# />
<cfdump var=#StructFindValue(Data,"2","all")# />
<cfdump var=#StructFindValue(Data,2.0,"all")# />
```

The first dump displays all values as `2` except for John who is `2.0`

However, the first two StructFindValue calls both only return `Bob`,`Jane`.

The third StructFindValue call returns `Joe`,`John`, `Alex`.

This basically demonstrates that CF's StructFindValue does a very crude comparison for checking equality, and basically isn't to be trusted when it comes to dealing with numbers.

(The issue doesn't exist with Railo, which probably uses the exact same comparison as it would when doing an `EQ` test, coercing types accordingly. Only tested on CF10,0,0,282462.)

To solve your problem, it seems you may need to manually walk the struct and replicate the behaviour of StructFindValue yourself.

Comment: Yep, CF10 seems to perform a *string* comparison on simple values .. ugh. So it is likely to be unreliable for everything except strings (ie numbers, dates, ...)